# OpenLayers 6 scaleLine too long

Tags: openlayers, scale-bar

I am displaying a 50 meters long lineString side by side with a scaleLine.
The 50 meters long scaleLine appears a little bit longer.

[image]

LineString Coordinates are : [1663006.541, 8176215.196, 1663056.542, 8176215.307000001]
and projection is EPSG:3949.

I changed the getPointResolution function for my 3949 projection like proposed in [OpenLayers 4 ScaleLine with projection answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259466/openlayers-4-scaleline-with-projection#new-answer?newreg=596c7192ddee4b4e9dd74b14501dc1e9). After a few tries I found an implementation `getPointResolution: function (r) { return r*1.01; }` that solved my problem. Now both length coincide. Yet I am not comfortable with this solution. Why are the length different in the first place and how sound is my solution ? I feel like I am resizing the world when I should be correcting the sizing tool.

Comment: There was a problem before version 6.4.0  https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11118  The latest version is working here https://codesandbox.io/s/3949-scale-2hn1g  If panned the line fits exactly under the bar.  Due to the projection being true only at the latitudes of true scale the true length is about 49.8545 meters.

Comment: @Mike. You were right. Tried version 6.6.1 of OpenLayers and it worked. Why don't you propose your comment as a solution. I'll make it the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem before version 6.4.0 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11118 The latest version is working here https://codesandbox.io/s/3949-scale-2hn1g If panned the line fits exactly under the bar. Due to the projection being true only at the latitudes of true scale the true length is about 49.8545 meters